# Pandas - Modify string values in each cell

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a pandas dataframe and I need to modify all values in a given string column.  Each column contains string values of the same length.  **The user provides the index they want to be replaced for each value**

- for example: `[1:3]` and the replacement value `"AAA"`.
- This would replace the string from values 1 to 3 with the value `AAA`.

How can I use the `applymap()`, `map()` or `apply()` function to get this done?

---

SOLUTION: Here is the final solution I went off of using the answer marked below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ffgghh','ffrtss','ffrtds'],
                     #'B':['ffrtss','ssgghh','d'],
                     'C':['qqttss',' 44','f']})
print df
old = ['g', 'r', 'z']
new = ['y', 'b', 'c']
vals = dict(zip(old, new))

pos = 2
for old, new in vals.items():
    df.ix[df['A'].str[pos] == old, 'A'] = df['A'].str.slice_replace(pos,pos + len(new),new)
print df
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`str.slice_replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.slice_replace.html):

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.slice_replace(1, 3, 'AAA')
```

Sample Input:

```
   A         B
0  w   abcdefg
1  x   bbbbbbb
2  y   ccccccc
3  z  zzzzzzzz
```

Sample Output:

```
   A          B
0  w   aAAAdefg
1  x   bAAAbbbb
2  y   cAAAcccc
3  z  zAAAzzzzz
```

Comment: @root - great answer, is it possible to add a condition to this as well, so say if position 1 is "A" replace with "B"?

Comment: Do you just have one condition, like an if-else statement, or multiple conditions, like an if-elif-else statement?

Comment: @root multiple: example let's say the value is 'abcdef'. I need to replace position 3 in the string if values are ['a','b','c'] to match ['d','e','f'] where index 0 of list 1 matched the replace value in list 2.

Answer (score 3):

IMO the most straightforward solution:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
        col
0   abcdefg
1   bbbbbbb
2   ccccccc
3  zzzzzzzz

In [9]: df.col = df.col.str[:1] + 'AAA' + df.col.str[4:]

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
        col
0   aAAAefg
1   bAAAbbb
2   cAAAccc
3  zAAAzzzz
```