# Add a string at the beggining of each element in a DataFrame(the number of hows is variably)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and i wanna add a string at the beggining of each element of a column(the number of hows is variably).

**Input:**

```
df = {'Name':['Jony', 'Mike', 'Joanna'], 'Color':['Blue', 'Red', 'Green']}

String = 'The favorite color is'
```

**Output:**

```
df = {'Name':['Jony', 'Mike', 'Joanna'], 'Color':['The favorite color is Blue', 'The favorite color is Red', 'The favorite color is Green']}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Modify string values in each cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38572815/pandas-modify-string-values-in-each-cell)

Comment: `df["Color"] = "The favorite color is " + df["Color"]`